# c# Substring Error

Tags: c#, substring

I'm showing a list of values in a view. It's working ok, but I need get only the first characters. I'm using Substring to implement it and it's working ok, in another case I use it for other value of my list but it's not working. I got this error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Html code:

```
<tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.LeadName</td>
                    <td>@item.CarrierCode</td>
                    <td>@item.OrderRef.Substring(0, 5)...</td>
                    <td>@item.Carrier</td>
                    <td>@item.Ref</td>
                    <td>@item.TicketRef.Substring(0, 5)</td>
                    <td>@item.NoofNts</td>
                    <td>@item.DebtorCode</td>
                    <td>@item.InvDate.ToString("d")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

"OrderRef" is working ok and the other one(TicketRef) doesn't work with the Substring but it's working without it.

Comment: Looks like one of those values is null in that case

Comment: Do you return model with your view?

Comment: `the other one doesn't work with the Substring` means `Ref` is not working?

Comment: The only way to figure this out it so debug your code and see what happens! One of your properties or instances is null.

Comment: The model is OK because I print everything OK without substring, problem is in the second case when I try to print using substring.

Comment: Probably, `OrderRef` is **null** just use an `if` statement and check whether it is or not...

Comment: I supposed the problem could be a null value but I have added a break point to make sure it's not null and all the values are null if I put substring and aren't null if I don't use substring..

Comment: I have rebuilt my project and it's working.. I don't know why. Anyway thanks for your help. I'll implement to check before to print the data if it's null to make sure its working ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like TicketRef is null.

I like to use a "NullSafe" extension (from [here](http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-one/)) for this kind of thing:

```
<td>@item.TicketRef.NullSafe(s => s.Substring(0, 5))...</td>

public static TResult NullSafe<TObj, TResult>(
    this TObj obj, 
    Func<TObj, TResult> func, 
    TResult ifNullReturn = default(TResult))
{
    return obj != null ? func(obj) : ifNullReturn;
}
```

Comment: @Markus: razor renders null and empty string the same, so it shouldn't matter in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Up to your comment that the error comes only when you use Substring it would mean than `OrderRef` is null, try to catch the NullReferenceException by try catch around the code to see the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the property values are null in this case. So you need to check before you call substring. If adjusted your sample so that the `OrderRef` property is checked before it is written to the output. You can adjust the spot where the `Substring` doesn't work in your code accordingly.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.LeadName</td>
            <td>@item.CarrierCode</td>
            <td>
                @if(item.OrderRef != null)
                {
                    @item.OrderRef.Substring(0, 5)
                    @Html.Raw("...");
                }
            </td>
            <td>@item.Carrier</td>
            <td>@item.Ref</td>
            <td>@item.TicketRef</td>
            <td>@item.NoofNts</td>
            <td>@item.DebtorCode</td>
            <td>@item.InvDate.ToString("d")</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

As a general approach, please read this excellent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) on NullReferenceExceptions and how to fix them.

Comment: This logic could also be done in the view model itself so that the view can focus on just displaying the values, making it simpler.